# Is it possible to open iphone phone number links with another app such as skype or change the default dialer?

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, default, skype

I'm desperately trying to find this info and have been searching for several days. I use wifi + skype on my iphone with no plan. All I want to do is when I click on a number in a web page, or in the contacts, is have that number open with another program like skype or google voice.

Is this possible or is there just no way around opening a number with the default dialer? I figured *somewhere* there's a value that determines which program is called to dial a number.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to jailbreak your phone first, and then you can try to figure out this, not other way

Comment: Oh, I figured that if I was digging through variables it would be obvious that it's already jailbroken. It is :)